# "New Web Application Project" vs. "Dynamic Web Project"

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-wtp, google-plugin-eclipse

How does the "New Web Application Project" option from Google Plugin for Eclipse (https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/creating_new_webapp) differ from the "Dynamic Web Project" option from Web Tools Platform (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform#dynamic_web_project)?  Can the Google Plugin for Eclipse be used to develop a "Dynamic Web Project" and/or an "Enterprise Application (EAR)" project as described in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform#enterprise_application_ear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jordan Fish from Google Cloud Platform Support had this answer:

> A Dynamic Web Project is using an Eclipse plugin (the Web Tools Platform) for creating the J2EE project and deploying an Enterprise Application (EAR) where as the New Web Application Project creates a project using the AppEngine plugin for eclipse.  At the end of the day the result is more or less the same, a web archive deployed to AppEngine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GWT, then you will likely want to use the New Web Application Project dialog so that you can configure the GWT settings for your project. It should also give you options for configuring GAE which I don't think that the Dynamic Web Project wizard does.